# Skype 4 doesn't function with Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, skype, pulseaudio, alsa

Can someone help me? When I start skype with Ubuntu 13.04 I get the this error:

```
skype 
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1018:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:612:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was in the same problem, couldn't get skype mic working at all

solution was: `sudo apt-get install libasound2-plugins:i386`

from here:

http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2091610.html